# Animation flickering problem

Tags: flicker, allegro5

This is the game loop in my code and the drawing code:

```
 float frames_per_second = 60;

    display_timer = al_create_timer(1/frames_per_second);
    queue = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_timer_event_source(display_timer));
    al_start_timer(display_timer);
    while(!end_game)
    {
      ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
      al_wait_for_event(queue, &event);
      if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) break;
      if(event.any.source == al_get_timer_event_source(display_timer))
      {update_display();}
      update_input();
    }

    void update_display()
    {
      al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255,255));
      draw_objects(); //this is just an al_draw_bitmap() call
      al_flip_display();
    }
```

The animation created by moving objects on screen flickers, I'm surprised by this since I write to the back buffer of the screen thus I expect double buffering. What can I do to correct the flickering? Thanks.

Comment: By default it is double buffered. Can you post the drawing code? The bit you have given is really irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: I've updated the post. I'm curious, how is the game loop irrelevant? That's what controls the rate of screen updates, I was thinking this must be an update rate problem.

Comment: It's irrelevant because if it is double buffered, it doesn't matter how fast you are refreshing the screen... you'll never get flickering. And by flickering, you do mean the screen goes white for a brief second and then you see the objects? (As opposed to shearing where the objects appear cut in half.) You may want to try `al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SINGLE_BUFFER, 0, ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);` before creating the display.

Comment: Well, I can move the image on screen with keys and the animation is not smooth. It's like it slows down in intervals. I did try al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SINGLE_BUFFER, 0, ALLEGRO_REQUIRE); I do not see any changes.

Comment: Ok, well that's a different problem. I'll post an answer that may help.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to the problem, you can check a timer by looking for the `ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER` event. You can use `event.timer.source` to check which timer it is, if you have more than one.

I think the main problem here is that you are drawing the graphics at 60fps but you are updating the input at an unlimited rate. This is actually backwards. You want to update the input at a fixed rate. You can draw the graphics as often as you like... although it makes no sense to update the graphics if nothing has changed.

So it should look something more like:

```
if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
{
   update_input();
   update_display();
}
```

However, this does not implement frame skipping if things get too slow. What you should do is set up the timer in a dedicated queue (that contains no other event sources). Then as long as there are events sitting in that dedicated timer queue, update the input.

Then update the display, assuming you've processed at least one tick. So you may, if things get too slow, do multiple input updates per drawn frame.

Comment: The animation doesn't flicker as much but it's still there. I'm guessing using `al_get_next_event` instead of `al_wait_for_event` in this case should be ok. I noticed an increase in memory usage with `al_wait_for_event`.